# MariaDB Connect engine pivoting table with date values

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I am working with an Innodb table in long format (training) and need to pivot this to wide format (pivTraining) reporting the latest (MAX???) date for each program.

I am using the following statement on Maria 10.5

```
CREATE TABLE pivTraining 
ENGINE=connect TABLE_TYPE=pivot
OPTION_LIST='PIVOTCOL=programID,FNCCOL=trainingDate,FUNCTION=MAX,USER=root,PASSWORD=######' 
SRCDEF='SELECT userName, CONCAT('Program_',programID) AS programID, MAX(trainingDate) AS trainingDate FROM training GROUP BY userName,programID';
```

and am trying to go from this:

```
MariaDB [db]> select * from training;                                                                                                                                                                                            +-----+----------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| tid | userName | programID | trainingDate | trainingExpiry |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
|   1 | kennjoh4 |         1 | 2023-12-17   |            365 |
|   2 | kennjoh4 |         1 | 2023-12-19   |            365 |
|   3 | kennjoh3 |         1 | 2023-12-19   |            365 |
|   4 | kennjoh4 |         1 | 2023-12-19   |            365 |
|   6 | kennjoh3 |         1 | 2023-12-21   |            365 |
|   7 | kennjoh3 |         1 | 2023-12-21   |            365 |
|  10 | kennjoh3 |         2 | 2022-12-05   |            365 |
|  11 | kennjoh  |         1 | 2023-10-04   |            365 |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------------+----------------+
```

to this:

```
MariaDB [db]> select * from pivTraining;                                                                                                                                                                                         +----------+------------+------------+
| userName | Program_1  | Program_2  |
+----------+------------+------------+
| kennjoh  | 2023-10-04 | NULL       |
| kennjoh3 | 2023-12-21 | 2022-12-05 |
| kennjoh4 | 2023-12-19 | NULL       |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

However what I'm getting is:

```
MariaDB [db]> select * from pivTraining;                                                                                                                                                                                         +----------+------------+------------+
| userName | Program_1  | Program_2  |
+----------+------------+------------+
| kennjoh  | 1970-01-01 | 1970-01-01 |
| kennjoh3 | 1970-01-01 | 1970-01-01 |
| kennjoh4 | 1970-01-01 | 1970-01-01 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

This looks to me like the connect engine is seeing the date type but doing something to it that results in a value of 0 hence the 1970-01-01

I have tried:

- removing the MAX function in the SRCDEF clause i.e. MAX(trainingDate) as trainingDate and removing the FUNCTION=MAX from the OPTIONS_LIST. I think this MAX is probably necessary though due otherwise the intermediate table gives the first value of trainingDate.
- adding DATE_FORMAT=YYYY-MM-DD to the options list
- reading the docs https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-pivot-table-type/#defining-a-pivot-table-from-a-source-table

Does anyone with experience of the connect engine know what may be going on here? I'm assuming it is something to do with the aggregating function.

outputs of describe:

```
MariaDB [db]> describe training;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tid            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userName       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| programID      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| trainingDate   | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trainingExpiry | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 365     |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [db]> describe pivTraining;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userName | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| 1        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 2        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Intermediate Table

```
MariaDB [db]> SELECT userName, 
CONCAT('Program_',programID) AS program, 
MAX(trainingDate) AS trainingDate, 
MAX(ADDDATE(trainingDate, INTERVAL trainingExpiry DAY)) AS expiryDate 
FROM training 
GROUP BY userName, programID;
+----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| userName | program   | trainingDate | expiryDate |
+----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| kennjoh  | Program_1 | 2023-10-04   | 2024-10-03 |
| kennjoh3 | Program_1 | 2023-12-21   | 2024-12-20 |
| kennjoh3 | Program_2 | 2022-12-05   | 2023-12-05 |
| kennjoh4 | Program_1 | 2023-12-19   | 2024-12-18 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: I'm aware of the possibility of doing this in a stored procedure https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pivoting-in-mariadb/ to get a pivoted output, but Ideally I'd like to do this as a view or pivot table in the database itself.  IF I have to, then I can implement this in PHP but would prefer to do it at the database level.

Comment: What you describe is definitely a bug. From what I see its not reported currently. Can you please report this as a [bug](https://jira.mariadb.org)?

Comment: @danblack thank you for confirming I'm not mad. Bug filed as https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-33082

Comment: Thank you. I only confirmed it was a bug, your "not madness" hasn't been fully assessed :-)